# Keypair asking for passphrase after changing permissions to 600

Tags: sftp, scp

this has been driving me mad and after hours searching here and everywhere else I am still unable to figure out why this is failing to work.

**Syntax**
sftp -o IdentityFile=/abc/efg/xxx/Priv_Key2.ppk -P 40007 at0223988_qa@inet-proxy-pg-1.us.adns.me.net

**Initially the output was as follows:** 
Permissions 0755 for '/abc/efg/xxx/Priv_Key2.ppk' are too open.

**So I went in, chmod 600 to lock down my private key, but now I get the following:** 
Enter passphrase for key /abc/efg/xxx/Priv_Key2.ppk:

The problem here is, there is no passphrase. I am logged in as the user that created this keypair and have no issue changing the permissions but sftp ignores the private key and errors out unless it is locked down as 600 but after I apply perms to 600 and rerun the sftp, it prompts me for a pw for this private key.

SCP does the same thing, asks for a passphrase if I change perms to 600.

What am I not seeing here? I am using PuttyCM, keygen was created in Putty KeyGen as SSH-2 RSA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am having the same exact problem. I'm pretty sure is just an issue with how we are changing the permissions.. would have been very nice to get some answer rather than the comments above asking to move this question...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by reloading my private key back into the PuTTy KeyGen and choosing "Conversions" tab at the top, exporting to OpenSSH, then using that version of the key. Not sure why this worked but must have to do with our version of redhat not wanting to read that .ppk